# Why almost website don't set caching expire for browser now?

Tags: language-agnostic

Why almost website don't set expire now .
Ago several year, i remember google set expire for their homepage ( i can access that don't even connect internet ).
But now almost website don't cache on browser . Why dont set expire , example only 2 mitutes ?

Comment: Please repost your question in your native language.

Comment: Do you mean "why websites don't use caching"? The answer to this, I suspect, is "because developers are lazy, and non-caching is the default in many apps where stateful behavior is needed" - PHP's session system in the default configuration is the prime example: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

Answer (score 2):

Using expire time makes sense on static content or content which is not sensitive to changes on a per-request basis. However, lately the websites get more and more dynamic and the providers would like to always show latest and up-to-date information. You wouldn't put an expires header on it then. Also, nowadays internet, hardware and bandwidth is extraordinary cheap as compared to years ago. As of now, you see the header more often only on *real* static content like images, CSS, JS, etc.

Comment: But news ( articles ) website is static content, it dont change in hours. Why dont set expire for browser ...

Comment: If you set expire time on 1 hour and 1 minute after you request it, a new news item is been added, you would only see it after 1 hour. And, 20 years ago with phone modems you pay basically $1 for every requested page, currently you can be continuously online for less than $1 per day. Information provision has got to be faster and more realtime.

Answer (score -1):

Because developers are lazy to estimate and set correct expires for all pages & types of resources.

Comment: then is main reason  lazy ? O_O

Comment: Lazy or don't know how to   ;)